# Issue Starting json-server Using npm start

Tags: json-server

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently learning `json-server` and have encountered an issue when attempting to start it within my project folder. Here's a brief overview of the problem:

I have installed `json-server` in my project folder, as shown in [img 1].
I created a new `db.json` file for testing, as depicted in [img 2].
When I run the script `npm start`, I encounter an error, and `json-server` fails to start, as seen in [img 3].
I've attempted to install `json-server` in a different folder and even installed it globally on my computer, but the issue persists with the same error. I'm unsure how to resolve this error, and I'm hoping to get guidance on how to make it work when running `npm start` with the start script as `json-server --watch db.json`.

Thank you for your assistance!

My error

```
> another-json-server@1.0.0 start D:\react-f8\react-dom\another-json-server
> json-server --watch db.json

file:///D:/react-f8/react-dom/another-json-server/node_modules/steno/lib/index.js:39
        this.#nextPromise ||= new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! another-json-server@1.0.0 start: `json-server --watch db.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the another-json-server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HungVV37\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-02T03_00_19_551Z-debug.log
```

I try to install again json-server in another folder, or install global on my computer but it doesn't work. It always throws the same error.

Comment: `||=` has been supported [since Node 15](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment), so every version currently in support (18, 20, 21) has it.

Answer (score 0):

Run into same issue. You need to update node to 15 or newer